# chrome background image display

Tags: html, google-chrome, parallax

I have a banner using the code below.  However in Google Chrome the fixed image doesn't show correctly as it does in Firefox or Safari.  I was wondering if there is a line that I am omitting.  It is HTML coding in a wysiwyg editor.

The site is:  http://javln1.mybigcommerce.com/

```
  padding: 10px 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-image: url(https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-yycscdze/product_images/uploaded_images/javln-auckland-skyline.png?t=1427668332);
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-color: rgb(39, 46, 55);
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: 50% 218.8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the `background-position` property two percentage values. For example:

```
background-position: 50% 100%;
```